# Calling Sidekiq delay on class methods displays error

Tags: ruby, delay, sidekiq

Calling delay on class method displays the following error:

```
    class Foo
      def self.bar
        puts "hello"
      end
    end



    Foo.delay.bar
```

Displays the following error

```
    {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass",
    "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Foo'\n- :bar\n- []\n"], "jid"=>"0000000", 
    "enqueued_at"=>1391440659.34402, "error_message"=>"undefined class/module Foo", 
    "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", "failed_at"=>2014-02-03 15:17:39 UTC, 
    "retry_count"=>0}
```

Any idea why?
Can we call delay on class methods?

Answer (score 1):

Restart your sidekiq and redis server.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and restart both redis and sidekiq didn't work.

I know it weird but it seems that sidekiq isn't loading everything well, anyway, the fix was to use a dedicated worker instead of a delayed class.

I hope it helps. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 0):

It tells you why: `undefined class/module Foo`

Sidekiq doesn't see your `Foo` class. Make sure Sidekiq is loaded in an environment that can see `Foo`.